# How do I enable health extension in azure vmss using Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform

I can't find documentation to add health and repair extension.
How do i enable health and repair in vmss using Terraform. I already created VMSS but I the health option is disable. I like to enable and configure in my terraform. Anyone has idea?.

If i define under vmss resource block ?

[image]

Comment: Do you use terraform resource `azurerm_linux_virtual_machine_scale_set` or `azurerm_windows_virtual_machine_scale_set`?

Comment: Did you try this solution https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/8120#issuecomment-694322558?

Comment: I am trying right now, let you know if it works. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the block has solved the issue

````
 resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine_scale_set" "consul_cluster" {
[...]
  extension {
    name                       = "ConsulHealthExtension"
    publisher                  = "Microsoft.ManagedServices"
    type                       = "ApplicationHealthLinux"
    type_handler_version       = "1.0"
    auto_upgrade_minor_version = false

    settings = jsonencode({
      protocol    = "http"
      port        = var.consul_health_port
      requestPath = "health"
    })
  
  } ```
````